# Displaying text from SQLite into a message object (Loop)

Tags: sqlite, lua, coronasdk

I have a database SQLite3 which stored some texts, such as dialogs between 2 characters. I also have a popup where the speeches are displayed in.

Right now, I can extract text from the database BUT my main problem is : how to display each line in a loop function? Like a slideshow, the text has to be displayed in the same object called `myMessage.text`

Here is my code:

```
function displaySpeech(event)
        for i=1,4 do        
            local result = "SELECT speech FROM speeches WHERE id="..i..""    
                for col1 in db:urows( result ) do
                    myMessage.text=col1
                    print(i)
                end
            i=i+1

        end
end
```

The function is called within a listener as shown below :

```
popup:addEventListener( 'tap', displaySpeech)
```

Once I tap on the popup, the function must display all the "lines" from 1 to 4, into the message.text with a delay for each one. Right now, my function (displaySpeech () ) cannot been incremented - the print(i) shows only the first line.

I know that the subject could be "huge", so first of all : Is it the good way to do ?

Perhaps, I'll need some `timer.performWithDelay()` functions  ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I found:

```
num = 1
function displaySpeech(character)
    displaySpeech_get(""..num.."", character)
    num = num + 1
end
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
function displaySpeech_get(number, character)
local varchar = character   
  for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM speeches WHERE character='"..character.."' LIMIT "..tostring(number)..",1") do
    myMessage.text=row.speech
  end
end
```